# JQuery not playing multiple sound files or delaying events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, settimeout

I have been attempting to go though a list of text and play the equivalent letter sound file. The code plays the last file in the string but does loop though every element (tried with an alert box). Im trying to play a sounds clip for every letter and I have tried using setTimeout to delay the instrumentation of the for loop but with no success. Does anyone have any insight on this? Also Im using jquery with a html5 web page.

```
function playSound(msg) {
                var sound_file_url = "snd/" + msg + ".wav" ;
                $('#sound').html("<embed src='"+sound_file_url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>");
                alert("Text: " + msg );
}

function startPoint() {
   var input = $("#text").val();
   for (var i = 0, j = input.length; i < j; i++) {
        if(input[i].match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/) ){
                setTimeout(playSound(input[i]), 500);
        }
    }
};
```

Long Time Lurker, first time poster. Thanks to all who took a peek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving context  as it will always be last i value. try following code. also you are calling `playSound` immediately.

```
   function playSound(msg) {

                console.log("Text: " + msg );
}

function startPoint() {

   var input = $("#text").val(), i = 0, j = input.length;
    function repeat(){
        if(i == j ) return;
        if(input[i].match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/) ){
             playSound( input[i]);
        }
        setTimeout(repeat, 500);
        i++;
    }
    repeat();
};​
```

Comment: I see my error with play sound! I tried that and it still doesnt delay the loop though :/ or allow multiple sounds to be played

Comment: are you getting any error?  try to increase value of delay from 500 to   2000

Comment: I set the delay to 2000 (2 seconds) and it still rips though the array then plays the last sound(no others) without delaying. I tested to make sure it went though every element using an alert

Comment: I thought it would do a timeout event per function call sorry :/

Comment: I made the changes have a look. let me know if you want make any other changes

Comment: I tried the sample above but it never goes though the loop once. I tried making a repeat function outside the loop after that passed the value of input but it would check every second and crash instantly

Comment: Yaa I forgot to call repeat first time.  made the change

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of the variable 'i'.

You can try like this pattern to keep variable 'i';

(function(newI){

```
playSound(newI);
```

})(i);

Also,

One more thing is that some browser only supports one channel of audio for HTML5 Audio API.